# Prevent Skrollr.js from scrolling to specific anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery, skrollr

im using Skrollr.js for my website im working on for some smooth scrolling to links.
On the same page im making a form with two tabs, Sign up or Log in, which are anchors as well. So now if you click on the tabs to switch between Sign up or Log in, the page will scroll down to the Id's of the form and I cant prevent it from doing that. I guess there is a conflict with Skrollr or something.

Is there a way to disable Skrollr for specific functions or can i disable anchor scrolling for specific links?

I used jquery for `event.preventDefault()` but that doesnt work

Any ideas? Alternatives?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, use other markup for the tabs, not anchor and change using javascript? also don`t use any id, class, data attribute that you use for skrollr on them.